# RAM not detected correctly

Tags: ram, memory-usage, 22.10

I just installed Ubuntu 22.10 in my laptop with 8 GB of RAM. I was doing some tests to test the performance of the pc when I notice that Ubuntu see only 6.7 GB instead of 8, and I don't understand why. I also notice that a lot of memory is used by the buff/cache even if I don't open anything. How can I solve this problem?
I put the result of `free -h` in order to show you the problem.

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        6,7Gi       2,0Gi       2,8Gi        50Mi       1,9Gi       4,4Gi
Swap:       4,0Gi          0B       4,0Gi
```

Comment: Do other methods of examining memory agree that total memory is 6.7GB? Try `cat /proc/meminfo`, `vmstat -s`, `top`. A high buff/cache memory isn't unusual and may be quickly available for other purposes. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390518/what-do-the-buff-cache-and-avail-mem-fields-in-top-mean.

Comment: With all the other methods the system seems to detect only 6,7 GB

Comment: The kernel can set aside some memory for its own use. What does `cat /var/log/dmesg.0 | grep "Memory:"` return? The various memory commands show usable RAM, which is always less that physically installed RAM for various reasons (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30324/why-does-linux-show-both-more-and-less-memory-than-i-physically-have-installed).

Comment: `[    0.058070] kernel: Memory: 6883660K/7274124K available (18440K kernel code, 4054K rwdata, 11244K rodata, 3148K init, 4924K bss, 390204K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)`

Comment: So it looks like it's detecting ~7GB physical memory, still not 8GB.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I have 8GB lol

Comment: It could be a kernel problem?

Comment: Run `sudo dmidecode --type 17` to see memory module size. You could have integrated graphics that is using some of your memory. Also, memory is usually sold as GB (1000^3) whereas Linux will be quoting GiB (1024^3). This could explain about 0.3GB of the difference and possibly 1GB of integrated graphics bringing it down to 6.7GB.

Comment: Indeed, I have integrated graphics in fact my laptop is the Huawei Matebook d15 with a R7 3700U, but I didn't know that integrated graphics takes memory from ram I thought it has its own memory. However the command says I have 2 4GB slots

Comment: No, a dGPU has its own memory. iGPUs always use the system's memory. It was always like this.

Comment: How can I see how many GB my iGPU use?

Comment: IF you can that information is in the motherboard's firmware (UEFI and previously BIOS).